# query all of the same id based on multiple true conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, case, where-clause

I have this table :

```
id  act  st_dt    end_dt    stats
1   a    01/01/20 05/01/20  done
1   b    04/01/20 09/02/20  done 
1   c    09/02/20 null      not done 
1   d    09/02/20 09/02/20  done
2   a    09/03/19 14/05/20  done 
2   b    09/02/20 25/06/20  done 
2   c    01/03/20 22/03/20  done
2   d    09/02/20 null      not done 
3   a    11/05/20 13/09/19  done 
3   b    09/02/20 04/07/20  done
3   c    01/02/20 30/02/20  done 
3   d    11/02/20 24/02/20  done
```

I want to query all activities 'act' of the same ID having activity a >= 01/01/20 and activity d status is done,
so the result should look like this:

```
id  act  st_dt    end_dt    stats
1   a    01/01/20 05/01/20  done
1   b    04/01/20 09/02/20  done 
1   c    09/02/20 null      not done 
1   d    09/02/20 09/02/20  done
```

the two conditions are met for this id, i did this :

```
select * from 
(
select 
 a.* ,
 case when (act = 'a' and end_dt > to_date('01/01/20','dd/mm/yy')) and (act = 'd' and status = 'done') then 1 end) flag
from 
 table a 
)
where flag = 1;
```

but it won't do the required,it'll query only activity 'a' and 'd'

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists`:

```
select a.*
from a
where exists (select 1
              from a a2
              where a2.id = a.id and a2.act = 'a' and a2.st_dt <= date '2020-01-01' 
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from a a2
              where a2.id = a.id and a2.act = 'd' and a2.stats = 'done'
             ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like to learn something new:

Creation of your table:

```
create table tab as 
with t (id,act, start_date, end_date, status) as
(
    select 1,'a',to_date('01/01/2020','dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('05/01/2020','dd/mm/yyyy'),  'done' from dual union all
    select 1,'b',to_date('04/01/2020','dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('09/02/2020','dd/mm/yyyy'),  'done'  from dual union all
    select 1,'c',to_date('09/02/2020','dd/mm/yyyy'), null                           ,  'not done'  from dual union all
    select 1,'d',to_date('09/02/2020','dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('09/02/2020','dd/mm/yyyy'),  'done' from dual union all
    select 2,'a',to_date('09/03/2019','dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('14/05/2020','dd/mm/yyyy'),  'done'  from dual union all
    select 2,'b',to_date('09/02/2020','dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('25/06/2020','dd/mm/yyyy'),  'done'  from dual union all
    select 2,'c',to_date('01/03/2020','dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('22/03/2020','dd/mm/yyyy'),  'done' from dual union all
    select 2,'d',to_date('09/02/2020','dd/mm/yyyy'), null                           ,  'not done'  from dual union all
    select 3,'a',to_date('11/05/2020','dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('13/09/2019','dd/mm/yyyy'),  'done'  from dual union all
    select 3,'b',to_date('09/02/2020','dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('04/07/2020','dd/mm/yyyy'),  'done' from dual union all
    select 3,'c',to_date('01/02/2020','dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('29/02/2020','dd/mm/yyyy'),  'done'  from dual union all --End_date is wrong in your input data I changed it to 29
    select 3,'d',to_date('11/02/2020','dd/mm/yyyy'), to_date('24/02/2020','dd/mm/yyyy'),  'done' from dual
)
select * from t
```

Here is the solution that works on 12c and later

```
select * from tab
match_recognize
(
    partition by id
    order by start_date
    all rows per match 
    pattern (a random_rows* d)
    define  a as act = 'a' and a.start_date >= date'2020-01-01',
            d as act = 'd' and d.status = 'done' 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

First get in two subqueries the `ID` of the *well started* and *well done* jobs.

`INTERSECT` the results to get jobs with both conditions and use this `ID`set in the `IN` predicate

Query

```
select *
from tab a
where id in (
  select id
  from tab a
  where (act = 'a' and st_dt >= to_date('01/01/20','dd/mm/yy')) 
 INTERSECT
  select id
  from tab a
  where (act = 'd' and stats = 'done')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using aggregated conditionals through an analytic function to determine whether both conditions are satisfied at the same time :

```
WITH a2 AS
(
SELECT a.*, SUM(CASE WHEN act = 'a' AND end_dt >= date'2020-01-01'
                     THEN 1 
                     ELSE 0 
                      END) 
            OVER(PARTITION BY id) *
           SUM(CASE WHEN act = 'd' AND stats = 'done'
                               THEN 1 
                               ELSE 0 
                                END) 
                      OVER(PARTITION BY id) AS satisfies                         
  FROM a
)
SELECT id, act, st_dt, end_dt, stats
  FROM a2
 WHERE satisfies = 1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cf141db953239f6b798896fbdc23b5d1)</kbd>